# How to generate two sets of random numbers in one html input?

Tags: javascript, html

How to do two functions in one js function that could put two sets of random numbers in one html input? I'd like to create function which generates two sets of random numbers by one click.

Generate 5 numbers from 1-50 and then 2 numbers  from 1-10. Two sets of numbers in one line.

This code doesn't work:

```js
function eurojackpot() {
  let result = new Set();
  while (result.size != 5) {
    result.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1);
  }
  document.getElementById("eurojackpot").innerText = [...result];
  let result = new Set();
  while (result.size != 2) {
    result.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    document.getElementById("eurojackpot2").innerText = [...result];
  }
}

eurojackpot();
```

```html
<div id="eurojackpot"></div>

<div id="eurojackpot2"></div>
```

What I want to achieve:

exp -   [2, 5, 15, 23, 49] + [1, 10]

Comment: What do you mean with "_it doesn't work_"? How do you know? What element is `#eurojackpot2`?

Comment: Can the same number occur multiple times? Can numbers from the second set occur in the first set?

Comment: You can't define a `let` more than once in the same block. Change to `var` or rename the variables or remove the second `let` and your code works: https://jsfiddle.net/o7b9hv0f/2/

Comment: You are showing two different ID....not one. Please provide a [mcve] along with expected results

Comment: @Teemu No result by clicking a button  `<div id="eurojackpot">
                        <em><b>EuroJackpot</b></em>
                    </div>`

                    `<input type="button" onclick="eurojackpot()" value="generate" onclick="eurojackpot2()" value="generate">`

Comment: But there is a result! You haven't took a look at the dev console ...There's an error message waiting for you.

Answer (score 1):

The code works when you remove the second "let" for result":

```
function eurojackpot() {
    let result = new Set();
    while(result.size != 5){
        result.add(Math.floor(Math.random()*50)+1);
    }
    document.getElementById("eurojackpot").innerText = [...result];
    result = new Set();
    while(result.size != 2){
        result.add(Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1);
    }
    document.getElementById("eurojackpot2").innerText = [...result];
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle that reproduces it:

https://jsfiddle.net/42bkucjy/

Answer (score 0):

Check below snippet,
Here you can specify min and max value (range in which you want your random number should be present) as first and second argument and total number of random element(In your case 5 number in first and 2 numbers in second) as third argument of randomWholeNum function.

Click on button it will generate random numbers. Now styling them as per your need.

```js
function randomWholeNum(min, max, total) {
  var arr = []
  while(arr.length < total){
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      if(arr.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
      arr[arr.length] = randomnumber;
  }
  return arr;
}



$(".generate").click(function(e){
  var rand_no1 = randomWholeNum(1, 50, 5);
  var rand_no2 = randomWholeNum(1, 10, 2);
  
  document.getElementById("eurojackpot").innerText = rand_no1;
  
  document.getElementById("eurojackpot2").innerText = rand_no2;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="eurojackpot"></p>
<p id="eurojackpot2"></p>
<button class="generate">Generate Random Number</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following will work for you:

```js
const pickRandom = (min,max)=>
  Math.floor(Math.random()*max)+min;

const pickFrom = array =>
  array[pickRandom(0,array.length-1)];

const pick = (array,amount) => {
  const recur = (numbers,array) => {
    if(numbers.length>=amount){
      return [numbers,array];
    }
    const picked = pickFrom(array);
    return recur(
      numbers.concat(picked),
      array.filter(item=>item!==picked)
    );
  }
  return recur([],array);
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener(
  "click",
  ()=>{
    const [jack1] = pick(
      Array.from(new Array(50),
      (x,index)=>index+1),5
    );
    const [jack2] = pick(
      Array.from(new Array(10),
      (x,index)=>index+1),2
    );
    document.querySelector("#eurojackpot").value=jack1.join(",");
    document.querySelector("#eurojackpot2").value=jack2.join(",");
  }
);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="eurojackpot">
<input type="text" id="eurojackpot2">
<button>make numbers</button>
```